# What are the file structure differences in bmp and jpg?

Tags: image

I am working on a microcontroller project which I need to think about what camera I should buy. I want to know what are the file structure differences between those formats.

***The following is something that I made it up, but it is the kind of information that I want to get.***

> The 1st five bytes of data in a bmp file are headers of file, the 6th byte
>   is the 1st R value of RGB. Every three bytes are the complete
>   information for a pixel of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Microsoft reference for BMP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q81498) (though there are variants) and the [W3C spec for JPEG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf); enumerating the differences is left to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks. I open BMP file everyday, but I have no knowledge of how it works. The information is really useful.